# A question about the centralizer structure of a nilpotent element of a semsimple Lie Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm reading the follow book: Nilpotent orbit on semisimple complex Lie Algebra . In the lemma $4.1.3$## Heading ## the autors uses the following assertion:

Let, $\{H,X,Y\}$ a $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple on a complex semisimple Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and consider a decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$ as a direct sum of irreductible $\mathfrak{a}$-modules, where $\mathfrak{a}$ is the subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ generated by $\{H,X,Y\}$. Then, each of such submodule contributes a $1$-dimensional subespace to $\mathfrak{g}^X=\{Y\in \mathfrak{g}|[X,Y]=0\}$.

I don't understand why it is true. The only thing i know is that since $H$ is semisimple, this implies that $\mathfrak{g}$ has a $ad_H$-eigenspaces decomposition, where each eigenspace is associated with a integer eigenvalue and the elments of the center of $X$ are associeted with positive eigenvalues of $ad_H$.

Comment: This follows from the representation theory of $sl_2$

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance Max. But can you explain me more?. I read the section 8 of Humpreys book: Introduction to Lie Algebras and representation theory, and i still can't understand how to proof. This migth to be easy, but i can't see that.

Comment: Every irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ has only 1-dimensional weight spaces and $\mathrm{Ker}(\mathrm{ad}(X))$ is a weight space in each irreducible rep (the highest weight space in that rep, in fact). So $\mathfrak{g}^X$ is just a sum of these highest weight spaces.